# Odd behavior of user-defined variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, user-variables

I've noticed something odd about user-defined variables:

Lets say I have this table:

```
 num_table
+---------+
| numbers |
|    3    |
|    6    |
|    9    |
+---------+
```

I can create a comma-separated list and store it in a user-defined variable like so:

```
SELECT @var := GROUP_CONCAT `numbers` from num_table;
```

Which will assign the value `3,6,9` to `@var`.

And here is the odd part. Running

```
SELECT 3 IN (@var)
```

returns 1, but running

```
SELECT 6 IN (@var)
```

returns 0.

It seems to me it should either work or not work. Any idea why it works only with the first number in the list?

Comment: I'd imagine it casts `3,6,9` to a number and ends up disregarding anything from the first non numeric character onwards and so ends up with 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `IN ()` with a variable and have that variable be treated as a list - only actual lists (perhaps of variables) can be used - i.e. `IN (1, 2, 3)` or `IN (@var1, @var2, @var3)`

Neither should work if `@var` contains '3, 6, 9' - so I suspect `@var` contains '3', though - can you verify its contents?

Martin might be on to something with the casting - I'd bet `'3' IN (@var)` returns nothing

Comment: OK @Martin seems to be correct. I can verify @var does contain the list because `SELECT @var LIKE '%6%'` retunrs `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IN ()` with a string variable - but you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead, which serves exactly this purpose:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(6, @var)
```

returns 2 - second position

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(7, @var)
```

returns NULL - no match